# Component within ListView does not update on AJAX refresh

Tags: java, wicket

I have a Wicket Panel that contains a ListView and then sub-items (Form controls), but when I press an inner CheckBox, the visibility of some of the sub-items should change.

However, calling WebMarkupContainer.setVisible(false) does not hide the items within the ListView after the ListView is redrawn during the AJAX update.

Code below:

```
public class ImagePanel extends Panel {

private ArrayList<ImageEntry> imageEntryList;

public class ImageEntry implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3987685200930059655L;

    public String thumbnail;
    public String filename;
    public boolean webDownloaded;
    public WebMarkupContainer fileUpload;
    public WebMarkupContainer webDownload;
}

public ImagePanel(String id) {
    this(id, IMAGE_NORMAL);
}

public ImagePanel(String id, int type) {
    super(id);
    this.type = type;

    wmc = new WebMarkupContainer ("wmc");
    wmc.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    add(wmc);

    imageEntryList = new ArrayList<ImageEntry>();
    ImageEntry imageEntry = new ImageEntry();
    imageEntry.thumbnail = "blah";
    imageEntry.filename = "blah";
    imageEntryList.add(imageEntry);

    ListView<ImageEntry> llv = new LargeImageListView("large_image_list", imageEntryList);
    wmc.add(llv);

    SmallImageListView slv = new SmallImageListView("small_image_list", imageEntryList);
    wmc.add(slv);
}

private final class SmallImageListView extends ListView<ImageEntry> {

    private SmallImageListView(String id, List<? extends ImageEntry> list) {
        super(id, list);
    }

    @Override
    protected void populateItem(final ListItem<ImageEntry> item) {

            ... 

        if (type == IMAGE_WIZARD) {
            item.getModelObject().fileUpload = showWizardFileUpload(item);
            item.getModelObject().webDownload = showWizardWebDownload(item);
            showSortUpDown(item);
            showWebCheckbox(item);
        }

    }
}


private void showWebCheckbox(final ListItem<ImageEntry> item) {

    AjaxCheckBox checkbox = new AjaxCheckBox("use_web_image", new PropertyModel<Boolean>(item.getModelObject(), "webDownloaded")) {

        public void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

            if (getModelObject()) {
                System.out.println("Show");
                item.getModelObject().fileUpload.setVisible(false);
                item.getModelObject().webDownload.setVisible(false);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Hide");
                item.getModelObject().fileUpload.setVisible(false);
                item.getModelObject().webDownload.setVisible(false);
            }

            target.add(wmc);
        }

    };

    item.add(checkbox);
}   

    ...
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ListView.setReuseItems(true) to ensure that the objects within the ListView are serialized correctly... Otherwise, you will receive a different object each time and the .setVisible() property will be reset to its default value (e.g. 'true').

```
slv.setReuseItems(true);
```

Comment: Amongst other things, this is why I prefer to override `isVisible()` instead. You need to be careful of course not to do too much processing in it but other than that your code becomes much cleaner and easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
WebMarkupContainer.add(new AttributeModifier("style", new Model("display:none")));
```

or

```
WebMarkupContainer.add(new AttributeAppender("style", new Model("display:none"), "="));
```

instead.